# How to empty trash of Google Team Drives

Tags: google-drive

There is a empty trash button in Trash of My Drive, but for Team Drives, I can only select the files to delete, then the 'Delete forever' button show up. I have thousands of files in the trash, is there a easy way to simply empty the whole trash?